# get path in linux environment variable for python app

Tags: python, linux, sqlite

in python I am using the following to set the path for a sqlite database:

```
APP_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.myapp')
SQLITE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'mydb.db')
```

I'd like to set the SQLITE_URI variable from os environment variables like:

```
SQLITE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLITE_DB_URI')
```

I tried:

vars.env

```
export SQLITE_DB_URI='sqlite:///home/me/.myapp/mydb.db'
```

But 1) I got an error (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file so the path is not correct, and 2) I'd like to use the $USER variablewithin the string locating the db withing the vars.env file

To set var from the vars.env file I an using a .sh file with:

```
set -o allexport
source pathto/vars.env
set +o allexport
```

Any suggestions?